# Jenkins re-run setup wizard

Tags: jenkins

Just installed latest Jenkins on Windows server.
Changed it to run as a service and my login no longer works. No problems, disable security for now.

But found out all my plug-ins are missing.
How can I have it rerun the setup wizard?

Answer (score 2):

As seen in [issue 310](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/310), you need on the server side to remove:

```
/usr/share/jenkins/ref/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state
/usr/share/jenkins/ref/jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion
```

(Search those files on your Windows Jenkins installation folder, to adapt those paths accordingly)

And you would relaunch Jenkins with `-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=true`

Answer (score 2):

I installed Jenkins through apt and my solution was a little different.

For Jenkins v2.140 I had to edit `/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml` and change the following line:

`<installStateName>NEW</installStateName>`

to

`<installStateName>RUNNING</installStateName>`

then restart Jenkins:

`sudo service jenkins restart`

Here is everything above in a script:

```
#! /bin/bash

sudo sed -i 's#<installStateName>NEW.*#<installStateName>RUNNING<\/installStateName>#g' /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
sudo service jenkins restart
```

Please note you will have to install all plugins and create users manually. I used the [Jenkins CLI](http://lifuzu.com/blog/2014/04/24/playing-with-jenkins-create-job/)

Comment: My solution is exactly the opposite - change from `RUNNING` to `NEW` will let me see the wizard again :)

Comment: As above, pretty sure you meant to say the opposite. You need to change that value from RUNNING to NEW.