# Install suggested plugins for jenkins

Tags: jenkins, plugins

I am quite new to Jenkins. I installed it but unfortunately I did not install any Plugins.
How can I get the suggested plugins installed on a running Jenkins environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is: you can just go to the **"Manage plugins"** ( `${JENKINS_URL}/pluginManager/` ) and pick them (see [caveat](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-63129)) yourself according to your needs. The master **suggested plugins list** is [available here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/jenkins/install/platform-plugins.json).

It would seem this has been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45698445/598141) before, but not accepted.

Depending if you have a previous install or have upgraded from a prior version,
you may see the following line in the `${JENKINS_HOME}/config.xml`:

From:`<installStateName>RUNNING</installStateName>`

AND/OR the following files in the `${JENKINS_HOME}` directory:

```
jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state
jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion
```

Removing the files and/or changing the `config.xml` to:`<installStateName>NEW</installStateName>` will reinstate the InstallWizrd. Only remove or change whatever exists; do not add anything. The files are created when you Save and Close the Wizard.

Storing the Jenkins version (ie: 2.303.2) into the two files will bypass the InstallWizard.

See @VonC's [response for Docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46478479/598141).

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Although I was searching for existing answers on that issue I did not find the post you mentioned.

Comment: this setting no longer appears in config.xml in latest LTS 2.303.2(observed on windows).

Comment: @joon, Updated to reflect current state and variations

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> C:\Users<usename>

and delete the folder `.jenkins`

then re-run the server