# Jenkins install default plugins after skipping during installation

Tags: jenkins

I had to skip past the default plugin install page to configure proxy and to fix an issue. But now I need to install default plugins. Is there a way restart the default plugin installation page without having to delete Jenkins container? Or is there  a list of default plugin names somewhere where I can manually install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install suggested plugins for jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63635421/install-suggested-plugins-for-jenkins)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a list with all of the default plugins, suggested for Jenkins version 2.60.3:

- Folders
- OWASP Markup Formatter
- Structs
- Pipeline: Step API
- Token Macro
- Build Timeout
- Credentials
- Trilead API
- SSH Credentials
- Plain Credentials
- Credentials Binding
- SCM API
- Pipeline: API
- Timestamper
- Script Security
- JUnit
- Matrix Project
- Resource Disposer
- Workspace Cleanup
- Ant
- Pipeline: Supporting APIs
- Durable Task
- Pipeline: Nodes and Processes
- Pipeline: SCM Step
- Pipeline: Groovy
- Pipeline: Job
- Display URL API
- Mailer
- Pipeline: Basic Steps
- Gradle
- Pipeline: Milestone Step
- Snakeyaml API
- Jackson 2 API
- Pipeline: Input Step
- Pipeline: Stage Step
- Pipeline Graph Analysis
- Pipeline: REST API
- Pipeline: Stage View
- Pipeline: Build Step
- Pipeline: Model API
- Pipeline: Declarative Extension Points API
- JSch dependency
- Git client
- GIT server
- Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries
- Branch API
- Pipeline: Multibranch
- Pipeline: Stage Tags Metadata
- Pipeline: Declarative
- Lockable Resources
- Pipeline
- OkHttp
- GitHub API
- Git
- GitHub
- GitHub Branch Source
- Pipeline: GitHub Groovy Libraries
- Subversion
- SSH Build Agents
- Matrix Authorization Strategy
- PAM Authentication
- LDAP
- Email Extension

seems like, better to re-install jenkins

Comment: I have [answered this more generally before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63645716/598141); consider upvoting my accepted answer.

Comment: Can you share the source of this list? Looking for updates to it.

Comment: @AhmedTawfik, looks like [this is the list of suggested plugins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/jenkins/install/platform-plugins.json) that Jenkins itself is using.

Answer (score 2):

We can get the suggested plugin from [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/jenkins/install/platform-plugins.json)

The suggested plugins are

```
ant
antisamy-markup-formatter
build-timeout
cloudbees-folder
credentials-binding
email-ext
git
github-branch-source
gradle
ldap
mailer
matrix-auth
pam-auth
pipeline-github-lib
pipeline-stage-view
ssh-slaves
timestamper
workflow-aggregator
ws-cleanup
```

Use the below command to get it

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/master/core/src/main/resources/jenkins/install/platform-plugins.json | jq -r -c '.[].plugins[] | select(.suggested==true) | .name' | sort
```

Expanded answer from Garth Smith Comment.